# One of the directory is not imported into the IntelliJ for my Maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have the .class files under the directory but somehow none of the other .java files picks up the methods from the .class files in one of the directories.

Kindly let me know where to check and where to import this particular directory.

Comment: the question lacks the information about your project structure and the way you are importing it in intelliJ?

Comment: Does it build from the command line Maven? How did you configure this directory with .class files as a dependency in pom.xml? Why do you use .class files in a directory instead of the .jar library?